# Andorid - Possible virus

Tags: antivirus

"I got an message on my android Galaxy S3, while reading my usual online newspaper on Chrome, the exact content is:

The page at download.com-01.mobi says:
POSSIBLE VIRUS

A website you visited could have infected your device with a virus.

Press OK for more information."

The above is the exact message that I got, and it's so weird... 
Is this something that I should be worried about?

Comment: Sounds like it's just a pop up, don't worry about it. Or if you are then factory reset the phone. Also you didn't ask a question!

Comment: Use an adblocker to get rid of it. These messages are a nuisance to lure you into a trap. There are many Q/A regarding adblockers on this website. You can search them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comments, that's just an ad that probably is trying to get you to install some form of malware.  In general, web pages cannot tell if you have a virus — and those that do, like McAfee's online scanner, will be obvious since you'll have to be engaging them on purpose!  (And they are likely PC-only anyways.)